# ORA-02287: sequence number not allowed here

Tags: oracle

I am trying to select values from two tables and insert them into one table and calculate the number of placements in total per year. I keep getting an error saying sequence not allowed here

```
DROP table placement_cal CASCADE CONSTRAINTS;

CREATE TABLE placement_cal(
    cal_id  INTEGER NOT NULL,
    year    INTEGER,
    no_of_placements INTEGER,
    CONSTRAINT  pk_cal_dim PRIMARY KEY (cal_id)
);


INSERT INTO placement_cal (
SELECT cal_id.nextval  , EXTRACT(YEAR FROM start_date) , count(placement_id)
FROM placement
group by year);

INSERT INTO placement_cal (
SELECT cal_id.nextval  , EXTRACT(YEAR FROM start_date) , count(placement_id)
FROM placement_two
group by year);
```

Comment: Unrelated, but: the parentheses around the select are totally useless for an `insert ... select ...` statement.

Comment: I was using entire query SELECT SQ_SESSION.nextval FROM DUAL inside a insert statement instead of using just SQ_SESSION.nextval

Answer (score 32):

You can get the reason in [FAQ](http://www.orafaq.com/wiki/ORA-02287)

> The following are the cases where you can't use a sequence:
>
> For a SELECT Statement:
>
> - In a WHERE clause
> - In a GROUP BY or ORDER BY clause
> - In a DISTINCT clause
> - Along with a UNION or INTERSECT or MINUS
> - In a sub-query

Comment: Small note to _In a sub-query_ point: I also encountered ORA-02287 using subquery with relation which is defined as table function. This produces error: `select * from table(sys.ku$_objnumset(1,2)) t where (3 not in (select column_value from t))` while this query fixes it: `with t as (select * from table(sys.ku$_objnumset(1,2)) t) select * from t where (3 not in (select column_value from t))`. It's interesting thing there is not any obvious occurence of sequence (perhaps some internals of table function).

Answer (score 17):

This query raises the exception:

```
SELECT cal_id.nextval  , EXTRACT(YEAR FROM start_date) , count(placement_id)
FROM placement
group by year;
```

This is because you cannot select a sequence value in a query with a `group by` clause.

Also, a `group by` clause must include all non-aggregate expressions from the `select` clause, which yours doesn't.  I'm guessing that `year` is the alias for `EXTRACT(YEAR FROM start_date)`, in which case this is the query you need:

```
INSERT INTO placement_cal
SELECT cal_id.nextval, year, cnt FROM
( SELECT EXTRACT(YEAR FROM start_date) year, count(placement_id) cnt
  FROM placement
  group by EXTRACT(YEAR FROM start_date)
);
```

Answer (score 5):

Surprised I didn't see an actual solution here. Using a CTE is a work around. Something like this should work:

```
INSERT INTO placement_cal (
    WITH tempPlacement AS (
        SELECT EXTRACT(YEAR FROM start_date) year, count(placement_id) cnt
        FROM placement
        group by EXTRACT(YEAR FROM start_date)
    ) SELECT cal_id.nextval, year, cnt FROM tempPlacement
);
```

Comment: Thank you very much, you saved me quite some research! This is the only answer providing an actual solution.

Answer (score 0):

Whenever you are inserting data in one table taking the data from the other table, do not use order by clause to avoid the sequence number not allowed Error.

Answer (score -3):

Do it like this 
You can use the sequence like this, For the group by part i recommend you follow the other answer from @Tony
    INSERT INTO placement_cal (
    cal_id.nextval  , EXTRACT(YEAR FROM start_date) , count(placement_id)
    FROM placement
    group by year);

```
INSERT INTO placement_cal (
cal_id.nextval  , EXTRACT(YEAR FROM start_date) , count(placement_id)
FROM placement_two
group by year);
```

Comment: Even the syntax is invalid.