# Hibernate INSERT INTO .. SELECT QuerySyntaxException with DISTINCT keyword

Tags: hibernate, select, hql, distinct, insert-into

I would like to do an INSERT INTO ... SELECT in HQL, where the select is DISTINCT:

```
INSERT INTO TAB1 (COL1, COL2) 
SELECT DISTINCT :const, A.SHORTID 
FROM TAB2 P, TAB3 A 
WHERE P.LASTTIME > :lastTime 
AND P.NAME LIKE A.LONGID || '%'
```

Substituting in the parameters this works as Oracle SQL, however Hibernate (5.2.4) doesn't seem to like DISTINCT in this case. It complains with an org.hibernate.hql.internal.ast.QuerySyntaxException that there is an

```
unexpected AST node: DISTINCT near line 1, column ..
```

I can use GROUP BY A.SHORTID instead in this case, but does Hibernate not support DISTINCT for INSERT INTO .. SELECT .. or is my HQL syntax with DISTINCT just wrong? Thank you.

EDIT: In this particular case I cannot use a GROUP BY as there is an Id column generated from a sequence (Hibernate adds the extra column and value to the insert, but [it appears Oracle does not allow selecting from a sequence together with GROUP BY or ORDER BY](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34546009/ora-02287-sequence-number-not-allowed-here)).

Comment: You should show us the actual Java code you used.

Comment: It is along these lines: org.hibernate.Session.createQuery(hqlAbove).setString("const", "const").setDate("lastTime", aDate).executeUpdate();. The above fails in the createQuery call; actually my GROUP BY suggestion fails in the executeUpdate call as Hibernate generates SQL that isn't acceptable to Oracle in this particular case because it includes a sequence value for a generated id in TAB1 in the background.

Comment: Insert ...Select Distinct ... works fine in HQL, i think the problem comes with :const. Try with something like  CAST(:const AS ...) instead.

Comment: Thank you, but that doesn't seem to be it - I have the same QuerySyntaxException for the DISTINCT keyword if I drop the idea of a prepared query and insert the :const string value directly in the HQL.