# SQL Oracle Sequence not allowed here using select

Tags: sql, oracle

Created a sequence using this:

```
CREATE SEQUENCE customers_seq
 START WITH     1000
 INCREMENT BY   1
 NOMAXVALUE
 ORDER;
```

but when I try this

```
SELECt customers_seq.Nextval from dual
```

I got this errors:

> ```
> ORA-02201: sequence not allowed here
> 02201. 00000 -  "sequence not allowed here"
> *Cause:    An attempt was made to reference a sequence in a from-list.
> *Action:   A sequence can only be referenced in a select-list.
> Error at Line: 8 Column: 34
> ```

How can I fix this error?

Comment: Works for me.  There is something else going on here.

Comment: Are you using this in a procedure or somewhere else? If so, try to provide complete code block. The select statement works fine.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [ORA-02287: sequence number not allowed here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34546009/ora-02287-sequence-number-not-allowed-here)

Comment: The error message states that the error is in line 8. you show us only one line. so this is not the real statement you show us here.

Comment: *An attempt was made to reference a sequence in a* **from-list.** You have NOT provided the full query. You possibly tried to use that innocuous select as a subquery in the from clause - which you cannot do e.g. `select * from sometable, ( select customers_seq.Nextval from dual )` which will fail

Comment: OldProgrammer it works on our prod server but when i try to replicate in my local the query does not work
JSapkota I query in sqldeveloper of oracle
miracle173 sorry i forgot to mention that line 1 to line 7 are comments...
Used_By_Already that is the full query line 1 to line 7 are comments

Answer (score 1):

I figured it out why select from dual is not working.
I have a sequence named dual in select * from user_sequences.

what i did was to "drop sequence dual"
then it work again

Answer (score 0):

Check  dialect is used is oracle dialect or not

```
<prop key="hibernate.dialect">org.hibernate.dialect.OracleDialect</prop>
```

Answer (score -1):

Please refer to [Orafaq](http://www.orafaq.com/wiki/ORA-02287) to find where a sequence cant be used.

The following are the cases where you can't use a sequence: 
For a SELECT Statement:

- In a WHERE clause
- In a GROUP BY or ORDER BY clause
- In a DISTINCT clause
- Along with a UNION or INTERSECT or MINUS
- In a sub-query
- Along with an ORDER BY clause

Comment: We should always use the [official Oracle documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/database/121/SQLRF/pseudocolumns002.htm#SQLRF00253) to rule on matters like this.

Comment: Yes. I will take care next time.. Thanks :)