# Fetching the sequence number from an Oracle database using jdbc .load()

Tags: oracle, jdbc, pyspark

I have a sequence number in my Oracle database that I am trying to fetch and increment using the following query: `SELECT TABLE.SEQ.NEXTVAL FROM DUAL` where `TABLE` is the table and `SEQ` is the sequence. It gets the value and increments it in DBeaver. However, when I run the following code:

```py
QUERY = "SELECT TABLE.SEQ.NEXTVAL FROM DUAL"
sqlContext.read.format("jdbc").options(url=URL, driver=DRIVER,QUERY=QUERY, user=USER,password=PASSWORD).load()
```

It gives me error:

```
py4j.protocol.Py4JJavaError: An error occurred while calling o98.load.
: java.sql.SQLSyntaxErrorException: ORA-02287: sequence number not allowed here

    at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CTTIoer.processError(T4CTTIoer.java:447)
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CTTIoer.processError(T4CTTIoer.java:396)
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4C8Oall.processError(T4C8Oall.java:951)
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CTTIfun.receive(T4CTTIfun.java:513)
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CTTIfun.doRPC(T4CTTIfun.java:227)
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4C8Oall.doOALL(T4C8Oall.java:531)
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CPreparedStatement.doOall8(T4CPreparedStatement.java:208)
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CPreparedStatement.executeForDescribe(T4CPreparedStatement.java:886)
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleStatement.executeMaybeDescribe(OracleStatement.java:1175)
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleStatement.doExecuteWithTimeout(OracleStatement.java:1296)
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.OraclePreparedStatement.executeInternal(OraclePreparedStatement.java:3613)
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.OraclePreparedStatement.executeQuery(OraclePreparedStatement.java:3657)
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.OraclePreparedStatementWrapper.executeQuery(OraclePreparedStatementWrapper.java:1495)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.jdbc.JDBCRDD$.resolveTable(JDBCRDD.scala:61)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.jdbc.JDBCRelation$.getSchema(JDBCRelation.scala:210)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.jdbc.JdbcRelationProvider.createRelation(JdbcRelationProvider.scala:35)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.DataSource.resolveRelation(DataSource.scala:318)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrameReader.loadV1Source(DataFrameReader.scala:223)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrameReader.load(DataFrameReader.scala:211)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrameReader.load(DataFrameReader.scala:167)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at py4j.reflection.MethodInvoker.invoke(MethodInvoker.java:244)
    at py4j.reflection.ReflectionEngine.invoke(ReflectionEngine.java:357)
    at py4j.Gateway.invoke(Gateway.java:282)
    at py4j.commands.AbstractCommand.invokeMethod(AbstractCommand.java:132)
    at py4j.commands.CallCommand.execute(CallCommand.java:79)
    at py4j.GatewayConnection.run(GatewayConnection.java:238)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
```

Comment: The error is pretty obvious "sequence number not allowed here". The reason is that within a pyspark query, it is considered as a subquery which is not allowed (see https://stackoverflow.com/a/34546044/5013752). But the main question is "why using spark to fetch a single number from db?"... you can probably do that in pure python

Comment: We are loading from a dataframe to oracle database using pyspark and it has 'append' mode. Now the sequence number is required for each row in the dataframe so we were trying to get the seq.nextval and for each row calling that query. would you recommend using a trigger instead? if we use pure python we would have to install cx-oracle library to connect to oracle which we don't want to do.

Comment: Let's assume your current code works. It would create a dataframe with a single line which is the next value of the SEQ. How do you get all the other values for each and every lines ? You create N dataframes  ? How you join them ? I believe the idea is to get a unique identifier. Then, just query the max of the "id", and sum it with a row_number. Or create a trigger but this is not compatible with bulk insert generally.

Comment: If we query the max of the 'id' then let's say we are not the only source inserting into oracle db table and other sources are referencing the seq number then they will get rejected because seq number <= 'id' after we insert.

Comment: Wouldn't this trigger work:

CREATE OR REPLACE TRIGGER SET_ID
BEFORE INSERT ON TBL
FOR EACH ROW
  WHEN (NEW.ID IS NULL AND NEW.CREATED_BY IN (OUR_UNIQUE_LIST))
BEGIN:
 NEW.ID = SELECT TABLE.SEQ.NEXTVAL FROM DUAL
END;

Comment: I would say : doest it work ? just try it :)

Comment: Which Oracle version? On 12.2+ you should use an [identity column](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/18/sqlrf/CREATE-TABLE.html#GUID-F9CE0CC3-13AE-4744-A43C-EAC7A71AAAB6__CJAECCFH) which would made the extra fetching of the `nexval`  not required... In previous versions use *trigger* or if you append the table from only *one process* at a time, get rid of sequence at all and simple use `max(id)` to assign the new `ID`s

Comment: In the identity column, would I have to create a new table? or can I assign a identity column to a table already created?

Comment: You may either create a new table with `identity`(and copy the data) or you may set the sequence as a `DEFAULT`value of the PK column - see my answer.

Answer (score 0):

The solution is to **not query the sequence**. Starting with 12.2 Oracle allows an [identity colum](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/18/sqlrf/CREATE-TABLE.html#GUID-F9CE0CC3-13AE-4744-A43C-EAC7A71AAAB6__CJAECCFH)n, where the ID is assigned  in the `INSERT`statement without a need of querying the `nextval`.

Unfortunately you can't *modify* existing *primary key* column to *identity* column, but you may *workaroud* the problem of getting the sequence value by setting the *sequence* as a `DEFALULT` value of the column - see [here](https://asktom.oracle.com/pls/apex/f?p=100:11:0::::P11_QUESTION_ID:9536678600346321004) for further details.

Example - Table with PK Colun `ID` filled from sequence `SEQ`

```
CREATE TABLE TAB 
(id INTEGER,
 col1 VARCHAR2(5), 
PRIMARY KEY (id));


select * from tab;

        ID COL1 
---------- -----
         1 y    
         2 z
```

So the `nextval`of the sequence is `3`

```
alter table TAB modify id default SEQ.nextval;
```

Now you may insert new records in the table and the `PK` will be assigned from the sequence automatically

```
insert into tab (col1) values('u');


select * from tab;

        ID COL1 
---------- -----
         1 y    
         2 z    
         3 u
```

You may still use the (same) sequence value explicite in the insert statement (as if you provide a value the `DEFAULT`clause is not firing).

```
insert into tab(id,col1) values(seq.nextval,'c');
```

If you want to assign a sequence `nextval` in case your application passes `NULL` such as

```
insert into tab(id,col1) values(null,'d');
```

you must use the `default on null` option

```
alter table TAB modify id default on null SEQ.nextval;
```

Comment: So if another process already uses "SELECT TABLE.SEQ.NEXTVAL FROM DUAL" to set values in primary key column, then will the 'alter table TAB modify id default SEQ.nextval' be ignored for that process? or will it overwrite the value?

Comment: Can you do default on null here?

Comment: Please see here:
https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e41084/statements_3001.htm#SQLRF01001 it says

 'A DEFAULT expression cannot contain references to other columns, the pseudocolumns CURRVAL, NEXTVAL, LEVEL, and ROWNUM, or date constants that are not fully specified.'