ORDS throws error while use SQL sequence Nextval
Team,
I have issues when try to expose GET NEXTVAL of SEQUENCE in ORDS service REST call.
The first 2 queries works well in ORDS GET.
1. select sysdate from dual
2. select last_number LAST  FROM user_sequences WHERE sequence_name = 'myseq' ;
3. select myseq.nextval from dual;

But the 3rd query works fine in SQL developer testing but when i invoke service in URL throws error as follows
The request could not be processed because an error occurred whilst attempting to evaluate a SQL statement associated with this resource. Verify that the URI and payload are correctly specified for the requested operation. If the issue persists then please contact the author of the resource. SQL Error Code: 2287, Error Message: ORA-02287: sequence number not allowed here


Maybe this will help https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34546009/ora-02287-sequence-number-not-allowed-here

Since ORA-02287 is an Oracle error I will suggest an edit to add the oracle tag

Are you sure the second query works? Because that would suggest that your sequence was defined as lowercase (myseq not MYSEQ).  In that instance, all references to the sequence would need to be "myseq" (ie, enclosed in quotres)
